# Need help separating array into sections for SQL

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am having array problems and need help simplifying the answer. Now without me pasting and typing out from a greasemonkey script(Javascript), I am just pasting a little code from it:

```
//THIS LINK IN BROWSER IS WHAT IM GETTING FROM THE JS SIDE OF THE CODE. NOW I CAN GET THE DATA= , ID=, AND &SA=,&DA=, &SPY=, AND &SENTRY=.
//THE &WEAPONS=0,4674,72|1,19,71|1,370,51|2,300,75|2,239,73|3,482,74|3,354,68

/php/Armory.php?data=ID=4518188&GOLD=6559178&SA=1805135169&DA=22677617&SPY=2841765807&SENTRY=2703794914&WEAPONS=0,4674,72|1,19,71|1,370,51|2,300,75|2,239,73|3,482,74|3,354,68
```

I am having problems in my PHP to separate the array after `&WEAPONS=`. I've tried several things like `split` or even `array_chunk`, and all I get is the same answer which is what shows after `weapons=` part when I `echo` or `print_r`.

I want to separate this into *3 sections* in PHP then have SQL insert the answer into the database if at all possible...
Below is some of the code I've done in PHP.

```
<?php
$list = $_REQUEST['WEAPONS'];
$list = explode("^", $list);
print_r(array_chunk($list, 3));
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0,4674,72|1,19,71|1,370,51|2,300,75|2,239,73|3,482,74|3,354,68 ) )
```

I want this part divided up into 3 parts for a table on DB which is `stat`, `wcount`, and `weaponNr`.
`0,4674,72|1,19,71|1,370,51|2,300,75|2,239,73|3,482,74|3,354,68`

When divided up it will look like this:

```
stat = 0
count = 4674
weaponNr = 72
--------
stat = 1
count = 19
weaponNr = 71
--------
stat = 1
count = 370
weaponNr = 51
etc.....
--------
```

Sorry for the long explanation but if anyone can help, I'd appreciate this cause I am not a pro at coding or asking how lol...

Answer (score 3):

To separate the string into an array this works:

```
function weaponsToArray($string) {
    $weapons = [];

    foreach (explode('|', $string) as $dataRow) {
        $data = explode(',', $dataRow);
        $weapons[] = [
            'stat' => $data[0],
            'count' => $data[1],
            'weaponNr' => $data[2],
        ];
    }

    return $weapons;
}

$weapons = weaponsToArray($_GET['WEAPONS']);
```